# How to transfer exponencial graph into java code

Tags: java, algorithm, anylogic

I am modeling the sarin attack in tokyo back in 1995 in Anylogic modeling software. Now I am dealing with the spread of the gas. Because it is an exponencial course. This is the graph I need to transfer to a code:

[image: Graph]

What I need to do is to write a loop which will go over all of the distances in the graph so I could check the position on map and set its sarin value based on that distance. I am not much of a programmer so I am sorry if this question is somehow badly explained.

It should look like this:

```
int sarin;

for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
sarin = sarin + someStep;
}
```

However how to calculate the step if its exponencial? Or even better, how to program it so its not discrete but the sarin value graduates? Thanks

Comment: Looks like `s = 5772 / Math.pow(i, 1.677)`

Comment: why do you need to write a loop? If you created the graph, you already know the function and you can easily associate the value based on the function itself... You can basically use the function directly.